# Function to split a string twice in javascript and sum the total marks

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am new to javascript and trying to write a function to calculate the total marks. I have some input text that i need to clean/split.

**Example:**

```
a, 80newlineb, 50newline
```

The output of the first array after splitting on 'newline' should be something like this:

```
["a, 80" , "b, 50"]
```

I'm then trying to loop through and create an additional array in a format from which i can calculate the total marks. Something like this:

```
function getTotal(input_text)
{
    const lines = input_text.split("newline");
    var arrayLength = lines.length;

    marks_array = [];

    for(var i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){
        lines[i].split(",");
        split = {module:lines[0], mark:lines[1]};
        module_marks.push(split);
    }

    some code

    return total_marks;
}
```

I've only ever really used php and think i am merging two languages into one and getting confused. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT** In this example the answer should be 130.

Comment: Just to be clear, the result of the above should be `130`?

Comment: @DavidThomas yep 130. I edited the post there!

Answer (score 1):

After splitting on the newline, filter out empty results, then split again on a comma and space. (not just on a comma, since you want only the numeric part on the right, not a number with a leading space.) That'll give you the first result you're looking for. Then, with that, map to the second item in each - the numeric part - and add them all up with `.reduce`.

```js
const input = `a, 80newlineb, 50newline`;
const lines = input
  .split('newline')
  .filter(Boolean) // remove empty lines
  .map(line => line.split(', '));
console.log(lines);
const sum = lines
  .map(line => line[1])
  .reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b), 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can achieve this. If all you need is the total [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on the digits with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to get an array of numbers, and then [iterate over that array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) adding the numbers to a new variable.

Note: the numbers you extract from the string will also be strings, so you have to coerce them to a number. You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array with `.map(Number)` to return a new array of integers, prefix the number before adding it to the total (`+number`), or use the [`Number` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number). This example uses the prefix method.

Note 2: I've deliberately missed out the part where you want `['a, 80' , 'b, 50']` as output because it's not clear whether it was just a stepping stone to your final result, or whether you we going to use it for something else. If it's the latter you may want to think about using an object to structure that data instead.

```js
const str = 'a, 80\nb, 50\n';
const numbers = str.match(/\d+/g);

let total = 0;

for (const number of numbers) {
  total += +number;
}

console.log(total);
```

Comment: basically, I have a back end that will take some poorly formatted grades in the format shown above from a URL. In many cases, there will be significantly more items/grades in the URL/input text. Having them as an array initially is not essential; it's just the way i would've thought to solve the same problem in PHP. I'm wondering if doing it this way will throw erroneous results if there are other numbers present in the url?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string by the `\n` and by the `,` at once using a regular expression.
And then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to add the numbers to a total if those are not `NaN` or empty strings.

```js
const inputText = "a, 80\nb, 50\n";

const getTotal = (text) =>
  text.split(/[\n|,]/).reduce((total, item) => {
    return isNaN(item) || item === "" ? total : total + parseInt(item);
  }, 0);

console.log(getTotal(inputText));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by using `RegEx` with the help of [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method along with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Live Demo **:**

```js
const inputStr = 'a, 80newlineb, 50newline';

var extractMarks = inputStr.match(/(\d+)/g);

const output = extractMarks.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b));

console.log(output);
```